# How to get Datagrid SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I would like to get the value stored in the first cell of my `DataGrid`. How can I parse that value when someone click on the update `Button` on my xaml?

**Xaml Code**

```
<DataGrid  Name="GridStream" Style="{StaticResource GridDatabase}" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Turquoise"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,2"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Stream Id" Width="*" Binding="{Binding streamid}"  />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Stream Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding streamname}" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="Action"></TextBlock>                            
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Name="BtnUpdateStream" Content="Update" Style="{StaticResource BtnForm}" Click="BtnUpdateStream_Click"/>
                    <Button Name="BtnDeleteStream" Content="Delete" Style="{StaticResource BtnForm}" Click="BtnDeleteStream_Click"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

**C# Snippet**

```
private void BtnUpdateStream_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int Id = (GridStream.SelectedItem as member).streamid;
    UpdateStream NewForm = new UpdateStream(Id);

    Console.WriteLine("The Id Value : {0} is", Id);
    //MessageBox.Show(Id);

    NewForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: I am populating the datagrid from a mysql database which works perfectly. The exception am getting is: The type or namespace name 'member' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: So what is "member"? It's supposed to be a custom type of yours...where did you get it from? You need to show you you set the ItemsSource and populate the DataGrid.

Comment: If you are using a DataView to bind to, you could cast SelectedItem to a DataRowView. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: Thanks champ! I got it, the DataView concept works like charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` is an `IEnumerable<member>`:

```
private void BtnUpdateStream_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var x = GridStream.SelectedItem as member;
    if (x != null)
    {
        int Id = x.streamid;
        UpdateStream NewForm = new UpdateStream(Id);
        NewForm.Show();
    }
}
```

If there is no select item or if the type of the currently selected item is anything else than `member`, the form won't be shown.

If the `ItemsSource` is set to a `DataView`, this should work:

```
var x = GridStream.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
if (x != null)
{
    int Id = Convert.ToInt32(x["streamid"]);
    UpdateStream NewForm = new UpdateStream(Id);
    NewForm.Show();
}
```

If you are binding to an `IEnumerable` of anonymous types, you may use the `dynamic` keyword

```
private void BtnUpdateStream_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic x = GridStream.SelectedItem;
    if (x != null)
    {
        int Id = x.streamid;
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't your answer basically the same as OP has with the only difference you are checking for a possible null?

Comment: @RandRandom: The "only" difference? Well, my code works :) It's unclear what error, if any, the OP gets. And you should certainly check for null in order to avoid getting a NullReferenceException. You also need to cast the appropriate type which my answer explains.